# Shared folder "Access is Denied" between Windows computers

Tags: windows-8, shared-folders

I have been trying for hours to accomplish what I thought would be an easy task, but am utterly baffled by Windows file sharing permissions. *Please* help me.

PC1 - Server - contains a shared folder called "backups"

PC2 - desktop

1. Created a user on server
2. Gave that user "Full Control" under "Share Permissions" tab
3. Navigated to \\server from my desktop and put in the user/pass
4. I can see the folder. When I click on it, Windows tells me "Access is Denied."

I've tried:

- Restarting
- Logging in/out
- Changing HomeeGroup sharing from "Allow Windows to Use user accounts"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I can see from your description you want to share a directory.
Since you use Windows 8 and I can see the "Security" tab you are using NTFS-filesystem.
It seems like you didn´t configure NTFS-permissions.

- Click on the "Security" Tab of the Folder you want to share.
- Then "Edit..."
- In the new window click "Add..."
- In the new window click "Advanced..."
- In the new window click "Find Now..."
- Select the user who needs the permission to acces the folder.
- Go back to the "Permissions for " dialog.
- Choose the user you added.
- Set permission to "Allow" / Full controll  (Or at least read permission)
- Click Apply.

On the sharing tab, the only entry you Need is:

- Everyone
- With permission "Full Controll".

You can manage the permissions with the NTFS-Permissions of the Security Tab.

The rest of the configuration looks correct.

Comment: I see now. There are essentially two levels of security. One at the NTFS level governed by the Security tab. Then a second at the sharing level which covers network access. I can safely leave "everyone" on at the sharing level and just use NTFS security to govern access. Makes sense?

Comment: @mrtsherman yes, you're right.

Comment: does not work at all. Read-only access to everyone refused.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick heads-up. When using an AD and sharing something to multiple people, using the authenticated users group over the everyone group is slightly more secure.

This is a default group when you do have an AD. It just means that if someone were to plug into a wall outlet they would also need a login that matches with your AD to get to your share.